# why can't install module in windows by ppm?

Tags: perl

I tried to install module... but It's can't work perfectly.. How can I solve this problem..

```
C:\Users\Program>ppm
PPM - Programmer's Package Manager version 3.1.
Copyright (c) 2001 ActiveState Corp. All Rights Reserved.
ActiveState is a devision of Sophos.

Entering interactive shell. Using Term::ReadLine::Stub as readline library.

Type 'help' to get started.

ppm> search Net::Address::IP::Local
Searching in Active Repositories
Error: No valid repositories:
Error: 404 Not Found
Error: 404 Not Found
ppm>
```

Answer (score 0):

you need to check your version of perl against the supported versions here http://code.activestate.com/ppm/Net-Address-IP-Local/

you can do

```
  perl -V
```

to see which version of perl you're running